# Lenovo Yoga pro 3 freeze while connected to wifi

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, laptop, drivers, broadcom

I purchased a lenovo yoga pro 3 and I have a huge number of problems that I'm not sure how to fix. I installed Linux Mint 20 cinamon.

```
uname -a
Linux bibi-ypga 5.4.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 19:20:19 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 20
Release:    20
Codename:   ulyana

 inxi -Fxz
System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-56-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.7 Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana 
  base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 80HE v: Lenovo YOGA 3 Pro-1370 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: VIUU4 v: 31900058 WIN serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO 
  v: A6CN38WW date: 09/30/2014 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 26.2 Wh condition: 39.0/44.0 Wh (89%) 
  model: Getac SDS-BAT status: Discharging 

CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel 5Y70 bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Broadwell rev: 4 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 10376 
  Speed: 799 MHz min/max: 500/2600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 799 2: 798 
  3: 798 4: 798 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5300 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 3200x1800~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 5300 (BDW GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel 
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
  Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio vendor: Lenovo 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-56-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network 
  Adapter 
  vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A port: 3040 bus ID: 01:00.0 
  IF-ID-1: usb0 state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 476.94 GiB used: 53.98 GiB (11.3%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: MZNTE512HMJH-000L2 size: 476.94 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 97.91 GiB used: 17.92 GiB (18.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-0 
  ID-2: /boot size: 3.87 GiB used: 303.5 MiB (7.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 53.0 C mobo: 29.8 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 222 Uptime: 14m Memory: 7.69 GiB used: 1.87 GiB (24.3%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
  inxi: 3.0.38
```

The most problematic is that the entire OS crash after a time of use, happen if the AC adapter is not connected and the battery is not at 100% and wifi is connected.

It doesn't respond anything, mouse not working, can't access to other tty's and I have to restart. And if I look syslog or dmesg at the time the system crash it doesn't show anything, so I don't know where to look!

I tried various workarounds, thinking that maybe is due to the drivers proprietary wifi:

First I disabled secure boot and installed bcmwl-kernel-source drivers.

I tried to put ideapad_laptop drivers into blacklist, editing /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf (font https://github.com/ecrampton/yoga2pro):

```
blacklist ideapad_laptop
```

And (font: https://github.com/longsleep/yoga3pro-linux/blob/master/Yoga%203%20Linux%20HOWTO.md):

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

Also I tried to deactivate wifi power saver, editing :

```
sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Where `2` is disabled (Font: https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55)

Also the sound stops working, but maybe I'll open another thread after fix this.

So any kind of sugestions will be apreciated!

Comment: Also asked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318239/lenovo-yoga-pro-3-freeze-while-connected-to-wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably solved, I'm testing a little bit more but everything seems to work fine:

What I did but it apparently didn't do nothing is:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo rmmod ideapad_laptop
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo su  
echo '#added to enable WiFi on Yoga 2 Pro'>>/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf   
echo 'blacklist ideapad_laptop'>>/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

As suggested here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro

But it seems that I found the key here: https://github.com/longsleep/yoga3pro-linux/blob/master/Yoga%203%20Linux%20HOWTO.md#generic-linux-kernel-tweaks-modifying-grub-boot-config , adding this lines to `/etc/default/grub`.

```
# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm i915.lvds_downclock=1 i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1"
```